# How to use .Contains and .IndexOf on a list of my own type

Tags: list, class, contains, indexof

New coder here,
I have a class which has multiple properties like this:

```
class Citizen
  {

      public string firstName { set; get; }
      public string lastName { set; get; }

      public Citizen(string FirstName, string LastName)
      {
         firstName = FirstName;
         lastName = LastName;
      }
```

Then I create a list of them:

```
class listOfCitizens
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         var citizenList = new List<Citizen> {
           new Citizen("Adam", "Johnson"),
           new Citizen("James", "Jameson"),
           new Citizen("John", "Adamsson") };
      }
```

My question is, how do I use `.Contains` and `.IndexOf` with this list? I'm trying to call the objects in the list, but can't figure out how without using a foreach -loop and that feels like a waste.